# How is HTML5 audio play position (and state) passed between different browsers, as MixCloud has managed?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

While playing a cloudcast in MixCloud in Chrome(31) I decided to move to Firefox, so copied the basic mix URL and on pasting into Firefox(26) was amazed to see the audio resume playing from the same position. The same happened when pasted into IE(10), although audio did not automatically resume playback.

I am not logged into the MixCloud site
There is no querystring appended to the audio item name in the URL
As I understand neither cookies nor local storage allow communication between browsers

I could only presume that it was by detecting the same IP address calling the same audio, but when pasted the link to another machine in my LAN it didn't restart from that same point.

So how is the positional information being passed between browsers, or am I missing another aspect? I would like to replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Please provide a replication procedure of what you observe. It's hard to tell how it works if not seen in action. Thanks!

Comment: Some screenshots may be useful too.

Comment: Consider that the "uniqueness" of a computer in the same lan may be differentiated by O.S., or something like that, maybe they just store IP + some info and so they restart audio from point you stopped only if the computer has a similar setup to yours.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube passes positional information through the URL, so you can link to a specific position. This is the correct approach to do that, as you should have the URL describe your content.

Right now I could not observe the behaviour you are talking about on MixCloud, but maybe you have stumbled upon a case where MixCloud does the same (refer to specific position through a URL fragment).

Comment: He specifically states url doesn't have a query string

Comment: Ok true, had overseen that. But the question is formulated more broadly in the title, so this answer might be valid for a general approach to the question, even if not matching the example of the OP (which is not replicable until now).